# Custom parameters from text file

Tags: java, math, text, equation

I am attempting to create a method which will either evaluate an expression saved as a string array or will return some sort of "equation object" to do the job. Essentially I have a String array which contains the following data:

equation[0] = side 1, equation[1] = operator (=,>,<), equation[2] = side 2.

Now, it is also important that I am able to use the side 1 and side two as variables in one of my objects. I am loading them in as such:

background = Ex Legionary;dexterity > 3;

Splitting at the semicolon for each condition. Any ideas? I have read that doing this directly may be impossible... if that is the case, any other ideas for how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: You could hold the "variable" element in `Map` of some kind.  This would provide you with the ability to look up the value associated with it

Comment: Can I assign variables to maps?

Comment: Technically, the map becomes the variable.  For each variable you need, you would add a entry to the map, named as required.  For example, instead of `dexterity` variable, you would place an entry in the map named `"dexterity"`.  When you need to know the value of `dexterity`, you would simply look it up in the map...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay... but how would the map know which person's dexterity I want to get? Can I set a map variable to dexterity and have it pull s.dexterity(when iterating through a list of the people)? Or do I need to set a different map item for each person's dexterity?

Comment: I'd have a `Map` per person/object.